# Как исправить ошибку в sqlite3?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Вообщем-то при моей попытки объединить две таблицы, выскакивает ошибка:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Kode.gorod`
Хотя нужная колонка присутствует, читал в других источниках, пишут, что обычно где-то не хватает кавычек, но у меня вроде всё проставлено. Конкретно ошибка в этой функции:

```
def Request_Toy_Res(self):
        self.db.c.execute(
            '''SELECT Tovar.tovar, Tovar.vid_tovara, Tovar.Kod, Kode.Izgotovitel, Kode.gorod FROM Tovar INNER JOIN Kode ON Tovar.Kod=Kode.Kod ''')
        for i in self.tab3.get_children():
            self.tab3.delete(i)
        for row in self.db.c.fetchall():
            self.tab3.insert('', 'end', values=row)
```

Ругается только на колонку Kode.gorod, когда её удаляю всё работает.

Comment: Значит нет такой колонки.

Comment: Очень странно, что у вас там колонки то с большой буквы, то с маленькой написаны. Не знаю существенно ли это для `sqlite`, но вы проверьте, может колонка называется `Gorod`, а не `gorod` )